# Preventing WireMock from recording certain responses

Tags: soap, wiremock

I'm using WireMock to mock some SOAP services.  One of them goes through a negotiation cycle for requests before finally authenticating with NTLM.  Currently WireMock is recording the first auth-fail response and then ignoring the rest as it has already recorded something for that URL/header combination.

Is there a way to either force it to record everything simply overwriting previous recordings or to provide it with a filter to ignore certain responses when recording?

Thanks for your help,

Joe